# Setting up Django with docker

Tags: django, docker

I am tried setting up django using docker but I am getting this error.

I have set up my Dockerfile and the docker-compose.yml.

> **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:

  db:

    image: postgres

  web:

    build: .

    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

    volumes:

      - .:/code

    ports:

      - "8000:8000"

    depends_on:

      - db
```

> **Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt /code/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /code/
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
web_1  | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think This particular error was [fixed in django 2.1](https://github.com/django/django/commit/931c60c5216bd71bc11f489e00e063331cf21f40#diff-f42ac10b4a1091330b3ae0c3d0d0a7cf)

You'll want to upgrade your requirements to be django>=2.1 to ensure you get this new version.

The comments on the commit indicate that this patch will not be backported to django 1.11.x which does not support python3

after change django version **re-ran docker-compose build**.

> Per the FAQ, Django 1.11.x is not compatible with Python 3
>
> Django 1.11.x reached end of mainstream support on December 2, 2017
>   and it receives only data loss and security fixes until its end of
>   life.